# How do you distinguish "immediately adjacent to" and "non-immediately adjacent to"?

Tags: grammar

Well, first, I am not even sure next means "immediately or non-immediately adjacent to", so correct me if I am wrong.

So here's a sentence:

> The car next to the building is red

It probably means that the car is not immediately adjacent to it, but damn close, but what about the other car next to the car?

> The car not immediately next to the building is blue

Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The second car from the building”?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't thought about that.